# How can I pass parameters to a partial view in mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, partial-views

I have a link like this:

```
 <a href='Member/MemberHome/Profile/Id'><span>Profile</span></a>
```

and when I click on this it will call this partial page:

```
 @{
    switch ((string)ViewBag.Details)
    {

        case "Profile":
        {
           @Html.Partial("_Profile"); break;
        }

    }
}
```

Partial page _Profile contains:

```
Html.Action("Action", "Controller", model.Paramter)
```

Example:

```
@Html.Action("MemberProfile", "Member", new { id=1 })   // id is always changing
```

My doubt is that how can I **pass this "Id" to model.parameter part**?

My controllers are:

```
 public ActionResult MemberHome(string id)
    {
        ViewBag.Details = id;
        return View();
    }
  public ActionResult MemberProfile(int id = 0)
    {
        MemberData md = new Member().GetMemberProfile(id);
        return PartialView("_ProfilePage",md);
    }
```

Comment: I don't get it. Perhaps if you add your controller and action it might help, but as it's written now, I don't understand your question.

Comment: see about [Partial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ee402926(v=vs.108).aspx) extension on msdn

Answer (score 400, accepted):

Your question is hard to understand, but if I'm getting the gist, you simply have some value in your main view that you want to access in a partial being rendered in that view.

If you just render a partial with just the partial name:

```
@Html.Partial("_SomePartial")
```

It will actually pass your model as an implicit parameter, the same as if you were to call:

```
@Html.Partial("_SomePartial", Model)
```

Now, in order for your partial to actually be able to use this, though, it too needs to have a defined model, for example:

```
@model Namespace.To.Your.Model

@Html.Action("MemberProfile", "Member", new { id = Model.Id })
```

Alternatively, if you're dealing with a value that's not on your view's model (it's in the ViewBag or a value generated in the view itself somehow, then you can pass a `ViewDataDictionary`

```
@Html.Partial("_SomePartial", new ViewDataDictionary { { "id", someInteger } });
```

And then:

```
@Html.Action("MemberProfile", "Member", new { id = ViewData["id"] })
```

As with the model, Razor will implicitly pass your partial the view's `ViewData` by default, so if you had `ViewBag.Id` in your view, then you can reference the same thing in your partial.

Comment: If you make your main model implement an interface, you can have the partial view use that interface as a model.  Then you can get a lot of reuse out of it.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Very explanatory answer as always :) Voted+

Comment: I had to use `@Html.Partial("_SomePartial", new Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewDataDictionary(this.ViewData) { { "id", someInteger } });` for this to work for me.  I'm using VS2015 DNX 4.5.1 if anyone else has this same issue.

Answer (score 67):

One of The Shortest method i found for single value while i was searching for myself, is just passing single string and setting string as model in view like this.

In your Partial calling side

```
@Html.Partial("ParitalAction", "String data to pass to partial")
```

And then binding the model with Partial View like this

```
@model string
```

and the using its value in Partial View like this

```
@Model
```

You can also play with other datatypes like array, int or more complex data types like IDictionary or something else.

Hope it helps,

Comment: This is neat! Exactly what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: My partial did not need my model, but I needed to preserve all the ViewData ModelState stuff.. this did the trick. In my partial view, I can still access ViewContext.ViewData.ModelState.ContainsKey(@Model.ToString())

Comment: This keeps throwing a `NullReferenceException`, object reference not set to an instance of an object, it's saying that `Model` is null. Any ideas?

Comment: OK, I was a bit premature upvoting this.  When I try this, I get the message that I'm trying to pass a view model to the partial view, but it's expecting a string.  I'm pretty certain I'm doing the right thing.  I've ended up creating a simple partial view model containing a single text property to get round this (and passing this in to partial view), as it was wasting too much time.

Answer (score 22):

Here is an extension method that will convert an object to a ViewDataDictionary.

```
public static ViewDataDictionary ToViewDataDictionary(this object values)
{
    var dictionary = new ViewDataDictionary();
    foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(values))
    {
        dictionary.Add(property.Name, property.GetValue(values));
    }
    return dictionary;
}
```

You can then use it in your view like so:

```
@Html.Partial("_MyPartial", new
{
    Property1 = "Value1",
    Property2 = "Value2"
}.ToViewDataDictionary())
```

Which is much nicer than the `new ViewDataDictionary { { "Property1", "Value1" } , { "Property2", "Value2" }}` syntax.

Then in your partial view, you can use `ViewBag` to access the properties from a dynamic object rather than indexed properties, e.g.

```
<p>@ViewBag.Property1</p>
<p>@ViewBag.Property2</p>
```

Comment: Where should I put this `ToViewDataDictionary` static method? Everywhere I try to put it I get some kind of a compiler error.

Comment: @CsabaToth this is an extension method. Just place it in a static class and then reference that class in your view.

Answer (score 12):

For Asp.Net core you better use

```
<partial name="_MyPartialView" model="MyModel" />
```

So for example

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   <partial name="_MyItemView" model="item" />
}
```

Comment: How do you pass parameters using this HTML helper?