# is there a way for update a variable in a view from partial view? razor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Suppose VIEW has this variable

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "carganuevamente";
    int ventaid = (Model.Venta == null ? 0 : Model.Venta.id);
}
```

then you open a partial view

```
@Html.Partial("selectcliente", Model.ListadoClientes);
```

how can I updata this variable since my partialview?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? `ventaid` is a server side variable. Once the view is rendered it no longer exists.

Comment: In view (parent) i have a object in null, which it has value when partial view  is closed, but not all page refresh, then ( i believe) the object in parent view stay in null

Answer (score 0):

You have different options:

1. Send ajax request and overwrite this variable with response data
2. Use global variables that you can access anywhere in project
3. Pass it to partial as model
4. Use viewbag or other collections

See more information here:

[How can I pass parameters to a partial view in mvc 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20799658/how-can-i-pass-parameters-to-a-partial-view-in-mvc-4)