# MVC partial View and controller code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I don't understand how a partial view is handled by controller, is it the same as a view? I made an example and it seems that partial view controller is never used

This is the example

Main View (test.cshtml):

```
<h2>Main View</h2>
@Html.Partial("_Partial", new { myNumber = 11 })
```

Partial View (_Partial.cshtml):

```
<h3>partial view</h3>
<p>my number is @Html.ViewBag.myNumber</p>
```

Controller (EtlMessagesController)

```
public ActionResult Test() {
    return View();
}

public ActionResult _Partial(int myNumber) {
    ViewBag.myNumber = myNumber;

    return PartialView();
}
```

When i invoke the main view I expect

> Main View
>
> partial view
>
> my number is 11

But the nummber 11 is not written. Am I missing something?

Comment: it's just an example to understand why partial view controller is not invoked. In my scenario the partial view neet to get a list of model objects and render a part of them

Comment: `@Html.Partial()` does not call a controller method - it just renders the html defined in the view named `"_Partial"`. You need `@Html.Action("_Partial", new { myNumber = 11 })` to call a server method and render the html it generates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found 3 ways thank to comments and answers:

1. @Html.Action (thank to Stephen Muecke comment on question)

`@Html.Partial()` does not call a controller method - it just renders the html defined in the view named "_Partial". You need `@Html.Action("_Partial", new { myNumber = 11 })` to call a server method and render the html it generates

2. Using a `ViewDataDictionary` (thanks to Mark Schevchenko answer and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20799658/how-can-i-pass-parameters-to-a-partial-view-in-mvc-4) on another question)

`@Html.Partial("_Partial", new { myNumber = 11 })` pass the second argument as the model, to pass parameters to controller `ViewDataDictionary` should be used instead

```
@Html.Partial("_Partial", new ViewDataDictionary { { "myNumber", 11 } }
```

3. Use the `integer` as partial view model (thanks to Mark Schevchenko answer)

See Mark Schevchenko answer. The cons of this way is that you can't have another model on your partial view

Answer (score 3):

Here your pass anonymous model to the partial view:

```
<h2>Main View</h2>
@Html.Partial("_Partial", new { myNumber = 11 })
```

Try use explicit model class or just `int`:

```
<h2>Main View</h2>
@Html.Partial("_Partial", 11)
```

Then you can use `@model` keyword in the partial view:

```
@model int
<h3>partial view</h3>
<p>my number is @Model</p>
```

As for:

```
public ActionResult _Partial(int myNumber) {
    ViewBag.myNumber = myNumber;

    return View();
}
```

You should use:

```
public ActionResult _Partial(int myNumber) {
    return PartialView("_Partial", 11);
}
```

The method `PartialView` can be used in AJAX scenarios to render a part of a HTML-page.

Comment: ad what if my partial view already have a model? Let's say it has @model `myCustomClass`, and i need an integer parameter `public ActionResult _Partial(int myNumber) { ...my code }`

Comment: F.e. `_Partial(new myCustomClass { integerField = myNumber })`.

Comment: thank you, the problem was slightly different but your example helped a lot