# Can not Call PartialView with Parameter in Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm Trying to call Partial View Into view i want to call parameterized method which is returing the partial view so how to call it.

My code is below.

**View**

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Appoinment/GetALLAppoinmentMedicine.cshtml",
    new List<HMS.Models.AppointmentViewModel> { new HMS.Models.AppointmentViewModel() }, 
    new ViewDataDictionary { { "aid", Model.AppoinmentIDP} });}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult GetALLAppoinmentMedicine(int aid)
{
    var idParam = new SqlParameter
    {
        ParameterName = "APPIDP",
        Value = aid
    };
    var SpResult = DB.Database.SqlQuery<AppointmentViewModel>("exec uspAppoinmentMedicine_GetAll @APPIDP", idParam).ToList<AppointmentViewModel>();
    IEnumerable<AppointmentViewModel> Result = SpResult.Select(s => new AppointmentViewModel
    {
        MadicineName = s.MadicineName,
        PotencyName = s.PotencyName,
        SizeofPills = s.SizeofPills,
        Dose = s.Dose,
        DoseType = s.DoseType,
        Repitation = s.Repitation,
        Quantity = s.Quantity,
        Duration = s.Duration
    });
    return View(Result);
}
```

Comment: `RenderPartial()` dos not call a server method. If you want to call your `GetALLAppoinmentMedicine(int aid)` method then you use `RenderAction()`

Comment: You can go through link.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20799658/how-can-i-pass-parameters-to-a-partial-view-in-mvc-4
Hope it helps..

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20799658/how-can-i-pass-parameters-to-a-partial-view-in-mvc-4 It works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use @{ Html.RenderAction("ChildAction","Home", new {param="abc"}):

It invokes the specified child action method and renders the result inline in the parent view.

Hope this will work.

Comment: Its Working Thanks Guys :)

Comment: @Azazkhan if its working, you should mark it as answer... so that other one believe on this answer and use it.

Answer (score 0):

The return type of Html.RenderAction is void that means it directly render the responses in View where return type of Html.Action is  MvcHtmlString you can catch its render view in the controller and modified it also by using following method

```
@{Html.RenderAction("GetALLAppoinmentMedicine", "ControllerName",new {uid= 1})}
```

If you want to use Ajax.ActionLink, replace your Html.ActionLink with:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
"Partial", 
"GetALLAppoinmentMedicine", 
"ControllerName", 
new AjaxOptions { aid = 1 }
)
```

and of course you need to include a holder in your page where the partial will be displayed:

```
<div id="myresult"></div>
```

Also don't forget to include:

```
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" 
  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

in your main view in order to enable Ajax.* helpers. And make sure that unobtrusive javascript is enabled in your web.config (it should be by default):

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameter or model as per your need..
dont forget to put the reference to the model in partial view

eg.@Html.Partial("_SomePartial", Model)